# "There is, up to Isomorphism, Only One Cyclic Group Structure of a Given Order"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In Fraleigh's *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*, I encountered this statement (p. 106). However, I hadn't seen a proof of the statement before. So, can anyone tell me why this is true?

> **Proposition.** There is, up to Isomorphism, Only One Cyclic Group Structure of a Given Order.

The implication here being that any two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic, which seems like a rather powerful tool. What is it about being cyclic that preserves the structural properties of groups of the same order?

Comment: I would say that it is the fact that cyclic means the group is generated by a single element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ and $H$ be cyclic groups of order $n$. Then there are $g\in G$ such that each element in $G$ can be written as $g^k$ for some $k$ and $h\in H$ such that each element in $H$ can be written as $h^k$ for some $k$. Can you find an isomorphism $f:G\to H$?

Comment: Of course! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is cyclic of order $n$, with generator $g$, then the map
$$
\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G,\quad k\mapsto g^k
$$
is a surjective group homomorphism. Therefore, by the homomorphism theorem
$$
G\cong\mathbb{Z}/\ker\varphi
$$
and, by cardinality reasons, $\ker\varphi=n\mathbb{Z}$. Thus every cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ and $H$ are cyclic groups of order $n$, then $G = \langle g \rangle$ and $H = \langle h \rangle$ for some $g \in G$ and $h \in H$. To find an isomorphism $\phi : G \to H$, think about the map $g^k \mapsto h^k$ where $1 \leq k \leq n$.